# How to embedded msi into a setup.exe and execute it silently?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Here's the requirement:
1. One single installation file. (aka. setup.exe) All the other files include the required dlls and msi itself must embedded in this setup.exe.
2. Frameless UI, which the pure msi doesn't support.

Firstly, we are using pure msi to provide the installation GUI, but then we found it's not support the frameless GUI. So we want to keep the single file and make our own frameless GUI.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to impliment an external UI handler.

You might find some of the links on http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/07/23/442584.aspx as a helpful starting point.

Comment: No, I mean the GUI still there, but just no windows frames like title bar and border..